# How to make GXT widgets editable/clickable?

Tags: java, gwt, gxt, pagingtoolbar

I trying to make my first GXT Paging Grid. So do not be strict:-) I render my grid according to example on official site. But buttons in toolbar do not work. When I trying to click on Next btn or Refresh or something else nothing happens. It even so not show alt message or highlight button. I tried to click this button in console with click() command but it's no reaction. I think I need to include some js to html page. Now I have this includes of CSS:

```
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="gxt/css/gxt-all.css"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="samples/css/resources.css"/>
```

Java code is right. Firstly I wrote it by myself and than I copied it from example to ensure that problem is not in java code. Adding a `toolbar.next()` load second page on start and than as early I can't change anything. Any ideas?

The same behavior in other widgets. I can't click buttons or edit cells in Editable Grid. Does any scripts that enables GXT components editable/clickable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found problem. It was in incorrect methods using. I put my code in onAttach method. It should be in constructor or in onRender method. Do not repeat my mistake